# Show Google my maps on android device

Tags: android

I created a custom map in Google Maps "My Maps". Now I want to show that map on an android device, but not just opening it as a web page but showing it using MapView or smth similar. I want to be able to center on a place I have marked on the map etc. My custom map is a map containing the location of all gas stations in a city.

Can someone please point me to the right direction or to an article describing this (I couldn't find anything).